# Is possible to transform a mesh into a texture? In 3DS max this is called "Render to Texture

Tags: mesh, texturing

I made a very simple lightning (lightning, thunder) mesh in Blender to use as effect, and i want to turn it in a texture, i notice that textures are smaller files, instead of using meshes. In 3DS max it is possible, but in Blender i don't know if it is possible, and if it is: how to do? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It called baking in Blender, you can find it in the render tab:

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/blender_render/bake.html

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/baking.html